# Return specific number of rows in result set from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, grid, limit, resultset

When we make a stored procedure call we pass input parameter of how many rows we want to get from result. Also, we want specific columns returned which is obtained through join operation on tables.

My doubt is can we return the result as table but if in that approach how to limit result rows to specific count which is passed as input parameter.

I also searched and found about using Fetch next rows only but can we use that without offset logic.

Can somebody suggest me if there is any better approach than above mentioned?

Comment: You could use `TOP`. It can even be used with a parameter. But if you want to limit the number of rows you would also want to use an order by so you always get the same rows.

Comment: Thanks Sean and Aaron for your suggestions. I could achieve my requirement by using TOP with input parameter.  I could learn something new very fast because of your suggestions. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could use TOP.

```
create or alter procedure TopTest
(
    @RowCount int
) as
    select top (@RowCount) *
    from sys.columns c
    order by c.name
```

And here is how you could do this using OFFSET/FETCH

```
create or alter procedure TopTestOffset
(
    @RowCount int
) as    
    select  *
    from sys.columns c
    order by c.name
    offset 0 rows
    fetch first (@RowCount) rows only
```

Comment: Thanks Sean! It really helped me to achieve what I was looking for. I couldn't upvote the answer as I do not have sufficient points but really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can however accept an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

TOP and OFFSET are easier to use if you need to get first n rows. If you need a range of rows (i.e. for paging), you can use CTE

```sql
            with vw as (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS RowNumber, 
                    columnlist 
                from YourTable      
            ) select * from vw
                where RowNumber between 1 and @NumberOfRows
```

Comment: Thanks Vasya! Really appreciate your help in providing me suggestions.